# Tornado run test with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua, tornado

I use Tornado and write some tests. And its everything fine.

Then I have used nginx for proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mine.local;
    location / {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

It work nice. But.

In tests I use `AsyncHTTPTestCase` and `get_app` method, which returns **Application**.

The problem is: tests "looks" on default 127.0.0.1:8000 - **Tornado** starts on the port 8000, and all `self.app.reverse_url('name')` returns **127.0.0.1:8000/path**.

But I need, that all requests from tests go to nginx (proxy):

**mine.local/path**

In **hosts** I have:

```
mine.local      127.0.0.1
```

In nginx I use some lua-scripts, that do all dirty-work. So I need, that tests make requests on **mine.local**, not on default 127.0.0.1:8000.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bind_unused_port():
    """Binds a server socket to an available port on localhost.

    Returns a tuple (socket, port).
    """
    [sock] = netutil.bind_sockets(8000, 'localhost', family=socket.AF_INET)
    port = sock.getsockname()[1]
    return sock, port

class MineTestCase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(AsyncHTTPTestCase, self).setUp()
        sock, port = bind_unused_port()
        self.__port = port

        self.http_client = self.get_http_client()
        self._app = self.get_app()
        self.http_server = self.get_http_server()
        self.http_server.add_sockets([sock])

    def get_url(self, path):
        url = '%s://%s:%s%s' % (self.get_protocol(), 'mine.local',
                                80, path)
        return url
```